# Using calc-like (calc Package) Commands within LaTeX3/expl3

Tags: calculations, latex3, expl3

In my pursue to switch as much as possible from `LaTeX2e` code to `LaTeX3/expl3`, I got stuck with the usage of some of the `calc` package facilities. I've read of the `l3calc` package, but it seems it is currently deprecated. In particular, I'm running into trouble with the `calc` pkg command `\widthof`. What's the `LaTeX3/expl3` way to proceed in this regard without declaring a box? I mean, something like `\widthof{This text}` chez `LaTeX3/expl3`.

To be more precise, I run into trouble with:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Loading explicitly the calc pkg doesn't help
%\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \g_tmp_dim
\dim_set:Nn \g_tmp_dim { \widthof{This ~ text} } % { 3pt } It works with this

\NewDocumentCommand \ShowWidth { }
 { \dim_use:N \g_tmp_dim }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ShowWidth
\end{document}
```

Maybe my trouble has something to do with the expansion of the `n` argument here and I should define a variant for the function `\dim_set:Nn` that manages the expansion in a different way? Just pondering over it...

Comment: There's nothing like `\widthof` in `expl3`; the function `\dim_set:Nn` wants a `<dimension expression>` as its second argument, which *must* be expandable; nothing like `\widthof` can be, because a box must be set for measuring it.

Comment: You could do something similar to what I did in my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126476/macro-to-calculate-baselineskip-for-given-font/126515#126515

Comment: @egreg: So the best we can do is defining our function to do this? It seems to me that it would be nice having this kind of functionality available as out-of-the-box tools from the LaTeX3 Kernel. I've always found very useful the ``calc``-based commands returning a length (or dimension) without requiring to set up a box beforehand.

Comment: @cgnieder: Please, see my answer to egreg. I was thinking precisely of doing that kind of thing, like defining a new function, or a ``xparse`` command to have that functionality, but I was hoping to have this already available in the LaTeX3 kernel itself. Does it make sense? What's the reason for not having it in the kernel itself given its usefulness?

Comment: Currently you have to define your own function for this. You'd need to ask @JosephWright or someone else from the team why it isn't provided, yet. (The LaTeX3 kernel (at least the stable part) currently more or less just is the programming layer expl3. That means the kernel is not complete, yet.)

Comment: @cgnieder: And... may I intrude and ask what you think of it? Do you find any reason why this kind of functionality should not be belong in the kernel itself?

Comment: All I'm saying is is that the kernel is not complete, yet. I'm not so sure this kind of command belongs to the _programming layer_ of it. That doesn't mean that it shouldn't be part of some part of the kernel. But it's not for me to decide and actually I don't care too much to be honest :)

Comment: @cgnieder: Ok. Thanks so much for the answer anyway ;-) To me, an answer in the sense of egreg's or yours would make for a valid answer. Would any of you post it?

Comment: @egreg: Would you please read my last comment addressed to cgnieder in the sense of posting an answer? I'd devise my own function or command, but I wouldn't post it because the discussion above makes to me more sense as an answer than providing such a function here.

Comment: @cgnieder Marcos ... the kernel is not complete but as far as I'm concerned the data type "dim" is. The goal of the core data types in expl3 is that they are fast and that rules out adding a parsing and intepretation layer to them that is triggered each time a "dim" operation happens. Just try \tracingall\setlength\textheight{100pt} - with calc 76 lines of tracing code without 5. That ratio roughly translates into speed (so a factor of 15-20). This is why the 2e kernel is carefully **not** using \setlength but lowlevel assignments.

Comment: @Marcos that doesn't rule out that a higher-level type will be provided as part of the designer interface but not as part of the programming interface. In fact there will be this kind of functionality on the designer level eventually.

Comment: @Frank Mittelbach: Thanks for the clarification. In regard to ``LaTeX3``, I need to improve my understanding on what belongs in what level.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the clarification! This confirms what I guessed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Functions such as `\dim_set:Nn` need that their second argument, in this case a `<dimension expression>`, is fully expandable. A function working similarly to `\widthof` cannot return a dimension expandably, because a box for doing the measurement must be set.

This doesn't mean that user level macros that work similarly to the behavior of `\setlength` with `calc` cannot be defined; however a parser for the expression must be defined.

By the way, nothing prevents you from using `\setlength` (with `calc`) inside LaTeX3 code (although it would be bad style). Or, for simple applications, use code similar to cgnieder's answer to [Macro to calculate \baselineskip for given font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126476/macro-to-calculate-baselineskip-for-given-font/126515#126515)